# How to fix problem with `fontspec` and `wrapfig`?

Tags: floats, fontspec, wrapfigure, wrap

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Fundamentals of Modern Physics}
\section{Introduction to quantum physics}
\subsection{Blackbody Radiation and Plank's Hypothesis}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{bulb}
\caption{A bulb}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

## Output without `fontspec`:

[image: Output without fontspec]

## Output with `fontspec`:

[image: Output with fontspec]

## Explanation and question(s):

I am trying to make a document in which I wrap a figure, as shown in the **MWE** posted above. The outputs that I obtain change based on if I use package `fontspec` or not, giving me an awful output when using it. It makes it incredibly hard to fit the wrapped image in the text:

- What is happening?
- How can one fix it?
- Why is the *attribute* `0.2\textwidth` being nulled-out/changed when using `fontspec`?
- **Why is this happening only with my images and not with images like `example-image-a`-?**

## Edit:

Image can be downloaded from [here](http://static.wixstatic.com/media/101231_a789d53a22c34e96b47e94b7ad4fedc9.jpg). A online file is available at [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/3127297gjvspx#/8719452/).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I had to switch the image of course, so I used `example-image-a`. It works fine with pdfLaTeX (without `fontspec`) or with LuaLaTeX (with `fontspec`) or with XeLaTeX (with `fontspec`). I get essentially the same result in all cases, although the fonts used differ slightly, of course. I'm using TeX Live 2015 updated in the last couple of days.

Comment: Aghhh, I am sorry, I forgot to post that, I did that too, and it worked fine, but when I loaded my own image, the problem began.

Comment: I just updated the questions list, added the deal with the images, I don't think the problem is only with this particular image, but if necessary I can upload it.

Comment: In that case, can you upload the image? We need to be able to reproduce the problem. If you can reproduce with one of the standard images, fine. But we need something. Right now, I'm guessing an issue with a bounding box. `graphicx` depends on the backend driver so it is quite possible for a buggy image to cause a problem with one engine but not another. I'm not sure why adding `fontspec` would be relevant, mind.

Comment: Also, is this XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: http://static.wixstatic.com/media/101231_a789d53a22c34e96b47e94b7ad4fedc9.jpg This is the image.

Comment: You can add it to your question, you know ;). I downloaded the image. I still get the correct output with `fontspec` with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: And actually I am using Overleaf to make this, they say they have multiple build engine options and that "In most cases we will automatically detect the right option to use".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27289/discussion-between-cfr-and-hans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OverLeaf's TeX Live installation is the root of the problem. It seems that OverLeaf is using XeLaTeX by default and, since their installation of TeX Live is not current, this features a bug which causes the problem. Switching to LuaLaTeX resolves the issue: this can be done by setting the engine explicitly in the Project options.

I've confirmed this on OverLeaf myself, and so has the OP. However, I can't figure out how to view the log file there when compilation succeeds but the output is unexpected. Moreover, with my own TL 2014 copy of XeLaTeX, I get a different, much more severe error which causes compilation to fail because `bulb.jpg` is not a DVI file. (That's what the error says. No idea why it expected a DVI file, mind.)

So the workaround is to switch to LuaLaTeX on OverLeaf. The proper fix, obviously, is to update the TeX installation.